# Angular 4 - How to display 3rdpartylicenses in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angular-material2

In my `package.json` the build process I use for my live [website](https://danielturcich.com/) `"build-prod": "ng build --prod --extract-licenses"`, I use `--extract-licenses` because I wish to have the licenses displayed in HTML on my website.

How would I go about displaying this `.txt` file in HTML with Angular?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be available at the root of the domain.

Here's a screenshot of my `dist` folder after running `ng build --prod` (which also extracts the licenses):

[image: Dist folder]

You should be able to access it by following this code:
(Oops! I forgot that you also have to install `@angular/common/http` and use the new `HttpClient`)

With `HttpClient` introduced recently in Angular 4:

```ts
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
export class AboutComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient){}
    license: string;
    ngOnInit(){
        this.http.get('/3rdpartylicenses.txt', {responseType: 'text'})
            .subscribe(result => {
                this.license = result;
            })
    }
}
```

Using the old `Http`:

```ts
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
export class AboutComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private http: Http){}
    license: string;
    ngOnInit(){
        this.http.get('/3rdpartylicenses.txt')
            .map(res => res.text())
            .subscribe(result => {
                this.license = result;
            })
    }
}
```

```html
<pre [innerText]="license"></pre>
```

---

EDIT:

You can also pipe the `license` property to an `async` pipe from a `HttpClient` request.

See the code below for more info:

Component:

```ts
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
export class AboutComponent {
  licenses: Observable<string>;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.licenses = http.get('/3rdpartylicenses.txt', { responseType: 'text' });
  }
}
```

Component template:

```html
<pre>
  <code>
    {{ licenses | async }}
  </code>
</pre>
```

Here's a [StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3rdpartylicenses) to play around with!

Comment: I'm trying to replicate your implementation but http.get is saying "Property 'get' does not exist on type 'HttpClient'. 

https://gyazo.com/d4c4812dc1b9f5624ac0afb8775adb34

Comment: @BuffetTime Sorry! I forgot to mention that `HttpClient` should be imported from `@angular/common/http`. I also added an example with the old `Http`.

Comment: getting an error from the new implementation. 

https://gyazo.com/096d7227c5e75fafe62ebdaf58287036

Argument of type '{ responseType: { new (data?: string): Text; prototype: Text; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders; observe?: "body"; params?: HttpParams; reportProgress?: boolean; respons...'.
  Types of property 'responseType' are incompatible.
    Type '{ new (data?: string): Text; prototype: Text; }' is not assignable to type '"json"'.
(property) responseType: {
    new (data?: string): Text;
    prototype: Text;
}

Comment: @BuffetTime Your `text` value is supposed to be just lowercase and encased in inverted commas. See my edited answer.